# solr 8.11 Field Types docs contradiction. Any guidance?

Tags: solr, solr8

I'm setting up my first Solr server via docker using solr:8.11.1-slim. I am gonna use the schema API to set up the schema for my core whose name is 'products'.
While reading the docs there seems to be false info on the docs for field types:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/field-types-included-with-solr.html

vs.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/schema-api.html

I followed the first guide to get info on what field types I can specify and am trying to send requests based on the second doc such as this:

```
{ 'add-field': { "name":"latlong", "type":"LatLongPointSpatialField", "multiValued":False, "stored":True, 'indexed': True } },
```

but Solr gives me back errors such as:

```
org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject: error processing commands, errors: [{add-field={name=latlong, type=LatLongPointSpatialField, multiValued=false, stored=true, indexed=true}, errorMessages=[Field 'latlong': Field type 'LatLongPointSpatialField' not found
```

So what gives? Am I misreading the docs or are they wrong or is something wrong with the solr 8.11.1 image in docker? Why does it not accept the field types I'm providing?

Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Comment: I believe you will  need to add a Field Type first that references LatLongPointSpatialField (see https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/schema-api.html#add-a-new-field-type) and then you'll a Field that will reference the Field Type (see https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/schema-api.html#add-a-new-field)

Comment: Yes, these are the available internally available field types, it does not mean that they are defined as field types _in the schema_.

Comment: Ah you are both correct. Looking through some default schemaTypes has one defined as 'location' which has the class LatLongPointSpatialField. Thank you for your help!